# open new WPF window without delay

Tags: c#, wpf

code to open and close form

```
    form f1 = new form();
    this.hide();
    f1.show();
```

i am using above code to open 2nd window but it take time to close and then open. i want to use such mechanism that has been used while installing new software where window will not reopen but content of same window changed.
other example: when click on my computer it will open new window but when we click on D: drive it opens in same window... so i am using same mechanism here

Comment: you can use customcontrols to do that

Comment: Use BringToFront/SendToBack  like this : `f1.BringToFront();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide it and set form2.Closed event to call this.Close().

```
this.Hide();
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close(); 
form2.Show();
```

Comment: but this creates duplicate windows